# How Toggle div in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#note').hide();
})

function clickme() {

    $('#note').show();

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#note').hide();
    }, 3000);
}
```

```css
#note{
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 999999;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="note">Read full content</div>

<button onclick="clickme()">click me</button>
<div>
The animation-duration property defines how long time an animation should take to complete. If the animation-duration property is not specified, no animation will occur, because the default value is 0s (0 seconds). 

In the example above we have specified when the style will change by using the keywords "from" and "to" (which represents 0% (start) and 100% (complete)).

It is also possible to use percent. By using percent, you can add as many style changes as you like.
</div>

<div>
The animation-duration property defines how long time an animation should take to complete. If the animation-duration property is not specified, no animation will occur, because the default value is 0s (0 seconds). 

In the example above we have specified when the style will change by using the keywords "from" and "to" (which represents 0% (start) and 100% (complete)).

It is also possible to use percent. By using percent, you can add as many style changes as you like.
</div>
```

Here am doing hide and show of div on button click.
But I want to display that div like bootstrap modal.
When I click button, div should toggle from top and display on above the content.which means it should not take separate space.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: text reminds me of https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Comment: @ashleedawg ofcourse its a w3schools text .I have added for sample data.Whats wrong in that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give it the `position: absolute` which will take the `#note` *div* out of the *normal document flow* (i.e. won't affect other *elements*) and place it above the *content*, in my example I've placed it in the *center* of the screen:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#note').hide();
});

function clickme(){
  $('#note').show();
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#note').hide();
  }, 3000);
}
```

```css
#note {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute; /* taken out of the normal document flow */
  left: 50%; /* moved right by 50% of the screen width */
  top: 50%; /* moved down by 50% of the screen height */
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%); /* moved left and up by half of its width and height to achieve the perfect center */
  z-index: 999999;
  /*float: right; has no affect*/
  background: Lavender; /* just for demo */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="note">Read full content</div>

<button onclick="clickme()">click me</button>
<div>
The animation-duration property defines how long time an animation should take to complete. If the animation-duration property is not specified, no animation will occur, because the default value is 0s (0 seconds). 

In the example above we have specified when the style will change by using the keywords "from" and "to" (which represents 0% (start) and 100% (complete)).

It is also possible to use percent. By using percent, you can add as many style changes as you like.
</div>

<div>
The animation-duration property defines how long time an animation should take to complete. If the animation-duration property is not specified, no animation will occur, because the default value is 0s (0 seconds). 

In the example above we have specified when the style will change by using the keywords "from" and "to" (which represents 0% (start) and 100% (complete)).

It is also possible to use percent. By using percent, you can add as many style changes as you like.
</div>
```